# C# copy image to clipboard as web object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Context: Winform, C#. .Net 4.0

I have an application where an image is uploaded to a web site.

Once this image is on the web, I would like to store it in the users Clipboard.

This object should be pastable to web.

Basically:
1) user hits save
2) image uploaded to web
3) store image object in clipboard
4) when the users "pastes", the image is pasted (which is refering to the uploaded file)

Best,
Jeff

Comment: Can you even show me an example website that allows pasting images?

Comment: You can do it with the Team Foundation Server web access

Comment: Use Clipboard object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx